# Cutting and reattaching sections of a polyresin figure

Tags: adhesives, cutting

I recently got a statue (Yes Man from Fallout: New Vegas, if you're curious :3) and I was looking to cut it to add electrical internals.
What is the best method of cutting and re-attaching pieces of polyresin?  (All I know about the actual composition is that [this retail link](https://gear.bethesda.net/products/new-vegas-yes-man-statue) describes it as "polyresin".)

Hand tools are much preferred.  Currently I was thinking of something such as a wire-saw and super glue, but I'm not sure!

Comment: Polyvinyl, or Polyurethane resin? They're both different materials, with potentially different answers.

Comment: The filler ( fiber glas, sand. etc) likely has more affect on cutting than the resin. My guess is the resin is polyester ,( very common).

Comment: I'm pretty sure its polyester resin, the website doesnt specify past "Polyresin" for context this is the link https://gear.bethesda.net/products/new-vegas-yes-man-statue

Comment: It should cut easily with various saws, etc.  For repairs, auto shops will have polyester kits available. I easily  cut up a polyester / fiberglas canoe with a reciprocal saw.

Comment: Not really on topic here, but if your toy is exactly the one from that link, then the best way of action is to put it in a glass box for showing it, instead of ruining it trying things. If you leave it alone, its value might increase over time. I you "fix" it, it will always be seen as junk. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut it with a jeweler's saw, according to the thickness of the polyresin.

Sand the surfaces that are to be joined.

Stick them together with Superglue or Duco Cement.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm gonna go with this method!